# Не сохраняется файл

Tags: c, файлы, winapi, дерево

Есть такая структура АВЛ-дерева:

```
struct avlleaf { // структура для представления узлов дерева
    char key[256];                                // Ключ
    unsigned long long int llupar;                // Числовой параметр
    long long int height;                         // Высота
    struct avlleaf* left;                        // Левый ребенок
    struct avlleaf* right;                       // Правый ребенок
};
```

Мне его после заполнения нужно сохранить

```
 struct avlleaf *tree = NULL;
 FILE *file;
 char tmpkey[256];
 ... // Наполнение дерева и считывание tmpkey (тут все норм - отладил)
 // Попытка открыть файл
 file = fopen (tmpkey, "wb");
 if (file == NULL) printf ("ERROR: FileSystem\n");
 // Запись дерева
 SaveTree(tree, file);
 // Закрытие файла
 fclose (file);
```

Ну и сама функция наполнения файла:

```
// Сохранение дерева
void SaveTree(struct avlleaf* tree, FILE * file){
  if(tree == NULL) return;

  fwrite(tree->key, 1, sizeof(tree->key), file);
  fwrite(&tree->llupar,  sizeof(unsigned long long int), 1, file);

  SaveTree(tree->right, file);
  SaveTree(tree->left , file);
}
```

Проблема в том, что файл не создается.

Я, например кладу /1.bin в tmpchar но поиск по windows его не находит.

В чем ошибка? И как исправить?

Comment: Пропишите полный путь к файлу, и он найдется :) А то что у вас, по логике надо искать в корне диска.

Comment: Приложениям запрещено создание файлов в корне системного диска.

Comment: А у меня путь задается как абсолютный, так относительный